# Subprocess in python: "not found"

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a line in my python script which goes like this:

```
subprocess.call(["./home/ubuntu/newproject/keygen.sh",username, password
], shell = True)
```

(of course these variables got an content) 
and the keygen looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo keygenerierung $1 $2 >> /tmp/logfile
touch /home/ubuntu/newproject/static/$1
```

when I manually try to open the path ./home/ubuntu/newproject/keygen.sh it works. Weird ! When I try to execute the python script it says: ./home/ubuntu/newproject/keygen.sh: not found

Comment: What does "manually try to open the path" mean? What program do you run, and what arguments do you give it?

Comment: it means that I just type it in the shell :) sorry I am form germany i do not talk so much english ^^

Comment: Oh, I see. You mean that you can execute the `keygen.sh` program from the shell prompt. Regardless, I'm glad that we've solved this problem.

Comment: yes that was what I mean ^^ and I solved the other problem too ... I just had to remove shell = True :) the downvote of the question is deserved xP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your filename begins with `.`, it is a *relative* path, and depends upon your current working directory. When you "manually open the path" (whatever that means), you are either in a different working directory, or you are actually specifying the related *absolute* path that begins with `/`.

I suppose that you actually meant to use an absolute path there. Get rid of the initial `.`.

Comment: dang I am stupid xD yes I meant an absolute path, thx ^^ now it finds the keygen.sh but it does not create a file in static ... but that is another problem :) thx for help